# Outlook Add-in get itemId of just sent email with office.js

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am writing an add-in using office.js that (currently) uses the email itemId to pass to my api which in turn calls Microsoft Graph 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/' + itemId, to get that email and store some information about it in a database.  This is working as planned for emails in a folder.

I want the same functionality for a new email, the user writes the email and when it's sent (native Outlook send button, not my addin doing the sending) I want to send it's itemId or other identifier to my api to pass onto Graph.  However as other questions have pointed out, the itemId changes, and ImmutableId's are not available to office.js

A comment on another question says to use CustomProperties.  Can I set a custom property on a new email? perhaps using OnMessageSend?  But even if this works, how do I then find/select that email again based on that property?  I do not want the user to have to go into their Sent Items to run my addin against that email.

Is there some way to get the 'just sent' email's itemId?  Perhaps using OnMessageSend to 'look' in the Sent Items and get the itemId from the most recent item?

Open to suggestions!

Comment: OnMessageSend is triggered before the mail is sent. So its not possible to get the item id of the sent mail item using OnMessageSend.

Answer (score 0):

The `itemId` property is blank for newly created items in Outlook. You must call the [saveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.4&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-messagecompose-saveasync-member(1)) method to get the ID assigned to the item. When invoked, this method saves the current message as a draft and returns the item ID via the callback function. In Outlook on the web or Outlook in online mode, the item is saved to the server. In Outlook in cached mode, the item is saved to the local cache. After that you may retrieve the property value (`itemId`) and use for Graph API calls.

If you need to identify items in Outlook (have any correlation with your db) you can use custom properties. The `CustomProperties` object represents custom properties that are specific to a particular mail item and specific to an Outlook add-in. For example, there might be a need for an add-in to save some data that's specific to the current message that activated the add-in. If the user revisits the same message in the future and activates the add-in again, the add-in will be able to retrieve the data that had been saved as custom properties.

To learn more about CustomProperties, see [Get and set add-in metadata for an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/metadata-for-an-outlook-add-in).

Comment: Just to add to this, for retrieving the item id in message compose on a saved item, use Office.context.mailbox.item.getItemIdAsync(callback) . You can find details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.8&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-messagecompose-getitemidasync-member(1)

Comment: Based on the OP description the `itemID` is retrieved in the code already, the problem is with new items.

Answer (score 0):

On the understanding that the itemId changes from draft, to outbox, to sent, I have used CustomProperties to set a known value to my own property.

I can confirm the emails are now sat in my sent items and reading them within outlook I can see the CustomProperties are correct.

Is there now some way to query the graph for that custom property such as `/me/messages?$filter=myid eq '{ABC123}'`?

Comment: Currently this is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.
The available graph apis for mail are mentioned here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true#common-use-cases

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT interesting, thank you.  However, I think I have managed to get it to work...
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-###### and ep/value eq '{"myCustomId":"myCustomValue"}')`